# elasticsearch update document frequently

Tags: elasticsearch

I am playing with ES. When one updates document in ES, ES automatically increments the version of the document.

While this is great, i wander if ES keeps the old documents too?

If it keeps the whole old documents, the storage on disk could grow a lot if I often update documents.

So in general , i am planning to do daily updates on all documents in some index. For 1 year i will have 365 updates on every document in one index. Is this OK to do ? Will i have 365 documents stored in ES ?

Is there a way to clean some old versions of the documents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it does not keep old documents, it's just for optimistic locking (concurrent updates).
http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/versioning/